# Where Gravity Forms (Wordpress plugin) save the temporal data?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, gravity

When you use a multi-page form built with `Gravity Forms` data must be saved in somewhere. I looked in sessions and database but I have not found.
Any suggestion is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Data is passed between pages populating all input elements. Only the current page is showed and the rest are hidden! Database is updated only when last page is submitted.